# How to avoid writing .pem while signing a csr?

Tags: tls, certificates, public-key-infrastructure, certificate-authority, openssl

I am using following command to sign a certificate,

```
openssl ca \
           -in client.csr \
           -keyfile server.key \
           -cert server.crt \
           -outdir ./some_dir \
           -policy policy_anything \
           -batch \
           -out client.crt \
           -notext
```

For each signing, it creates a `.pem` file in directory specified with `-outdir` option. I don't need `.pem` files anymore because I have specified required filename with `-out` option.

I tried it without `-outdir` option but in that case it used default `outdir` specified in openssl.conf. I know removing `.pem` after creation is a way, but looking for better way to handle this. **How can I avoid unwanted .pem file creation?**

*Thanks for your time!*

Comment: Have you tried using the `-outform DER` option?

Comment: @BadSkillz, Thanks for reply. `-outform` is for `openssl x509`, using with `openssl ca` prints help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, per the sourcecode you can't prevent the writing of `$outdir/$serial.pem` and still get your (desired) `-out`. You could put `$outdir` someplace like `/tmp` that gets discarded frequently; or on an OS that allows you to add new filesystem types (Linux at least) you could create a filesystem type that implements a directory such that anything created in it is discarded -- but that seems a lot of work to avoid creating a few files that don't hurt anything.

Answer (score 0):

As described on the [manpage](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/apps/ca.html) for openSSL:

> -out filename
>
> the output file to output certificates to. The default is standard output. The certificate details will also be printed out to this file in PEM format (except that -spkac outputs DER format).

So it seems this will always write the certificate in a PEM format. You could choose to write these to `/dev/null/` or make a script to clean out these unwanted certificates.

Comment: Q is not about the *format* of the `-out` file, but about the *additional* file in `-outdir`,.